# Travel with an outstanding warrant

Tags: visas, air-travel, usa, customs-and-immigration, legal

I need help!!! My story is I got caught with my two friends because of Marijuana. I had court date and rescheduled it but I didn't show up for the hearing, and I have a warrant issued for my arrest. However, right now I'm outside U.S, and I'm coming back in August.

I'm trying to solve this issue. Do I have to get a lawyer or whatever I just need to enter the US, and I'll meet the judge and follow their instructions. I'm international student on a study Visa

May I enter the US, or will the Immigration stop me?

Comment: If you have a warrant issued for your arrest you should get a lawyer like yesterday.

Comment: @Karlson if I get a lawyer, immigration may let me enter the US..my goal is to enter the US and complete my degree..

Comment: If you get a lawyer you will have to ask him to see what happens with immigration and other matters because a conviction on drug charges may just get you kicked out of the country.

Comment: If you really intend to return to the US, you _absolutely_ need a lawyer.. unless you intend to spend some time in an American jail. Unless you take care of this now, you should count on being arrested the moment you show up at immigration.

Comment: How can I find a lawyer good at immigration, and maybe how much cost...let me know if you ha ve a good lawyer..thx tho all

Comment: @Williabdull You need a lawyer that specializes in the charges made against you for which I am assuming a bench warrant has been issued.  Immigration in this case is incidental.

Comment: @Williabdull: And before attempting to re-enter the US, you may want to see whether your school has suspended (or expelled) you and, more importantly, whether your visa has been revoked. The issuance of a bench warrant could result in either, or both, happening.

Comment: Are you a US citizen? If so, immigration can't stop you from entering. They could arrest you, though.

Comment: @phoog OP is on a student visa.

Comment: @Karlson there is some reason to infer that, but I see nothing stating that explicitly or implying it unambiguously.

Comment: @phoog I edited it out to make ti more travel related.

Comment: @Karlson Removing the OP's immigration status from a question about immigration procedures is hardly an improvement.

Answer (score 5):

From the [CBP](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/cbp-search-authority) website regarding warrant check:

> Many travelers wonder if CBP is alerted when an inbound passenger has a warrant for their arrest issued. Yes, CBP is alerted. In the air passenger environment, air carriers transmit passenger information to CBP through the Advance Passenger Information System (APIS). CBP officers also rely on the Interagency Border Inspection System (IBIS) to determine which individuals to target for secondary examination upon arrival in the United States.

So it is quite likely that you will be detained, searched, and quite possibly arrested as soon as you arrive at the border.  What happens after I am not sure but it is quite likely that you will be delivered transported directly to courthouse to answer the charges from which you have skipped out.

Comment: You know what is weird is that last summer I went out side US and come back, and nobody stopped me,, my warrant issued about 2015 September, so before Christmas and I enter US by Dallas airport legal

Comment: @Williabdull Congratulations.  You're welcome to try and take your chances.

Comment: I don't want to try again because I'm scared.. And I don't want to run from justice.. The court that has my case they could deal with my situation by giving me a date to attend and drop the warrant on my name.. Is there way to drop. Warrant?

Comment: @Williabdull Get a lawyer!

Comment: Find a lawyer who works in the city or area where you were arrested. You want someone who does criminal defense, especially drug cases. Many will do a free initial consultation. Tell him/her the story, explain your immigration concerns. They can then advise you and will let you know how much they charge and what they propose to do on your behalf. You might want to speak to more than one lawyer and pick whoever you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: Doesn't all of this completely depend on the jurisdiction of the original arrest, whether the warrant is Federal or State, etc. There are simply too many unknowns that the only correct answer must be talk to a lawyer.

Comment: Make sure you pick a lawyer that has some familiarity with immigration issues. People have got caught by making plea deals with light direct penalties, but serious immigration consequences.

Comment: Hello, wish everyone doing well..I have a question..! I paid immigration lawyer for nothing. In other words, I paid a lawyer 500$ just let me enter the US, however, he didn't do anything, also in (Missouri State website cases) doesn't show the lawyer I hird.. He just took my money for nothing.. I can refund my money by bank..or there is a contract between us?.. The method payment was by phone, that office lawyer doesn't accept others(cash, online..) at the end, the lawyer doesn't provide me any help.. And I enter the us with out his help

Comment: @Williabdull That's an entirely different question that requires a lot of explanation of details and many other things not applicable to this forum.  You can try your luck in chat but I doubt that anyone would be able to help getting you a refund from a lawyer.